# How can I create a simple tab?

Tags: 7

I'd like to create a tab like the one show in the screenshot for a simple contact address list.

[image]

or see this drupal site [HERE](http://upgrade.boombatower.com/tools)

I have "contact one," "contact two,"  and "contact three."
I want to put some text under each contact section.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to use [QuickTabs](http://drupal.org/project/quicktabs). I am using it on [my website](http://www.glumbo.com/) (check near the bottom). It seems to be exactly what you want to do. Under each quick tab, you can display nodes, views, blocks or other quick tabs.

Comment: Thank you!!!  that is what i'm looking. i'm not sure i know how to put the tab like you did under putting on node. when i set the tab block on content place i see the tab all over the page but i want to put the tab only under contact node.  bay the way have a nice page :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do. Can you show me  your site?

Comment: Thank you i have created a nice contact tab using quicktabs. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use an implementation of hook_menu(). Here's an example in code:

```
function services_menu() {
  $items['services'] = array(
    'title' => 'Services',
    'description' => 'Description of services',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'page callback' => 'services_page_callback',
  );
  $items['services/development'] = array(
    'title' => 'Drupal Development',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
    'weight' => -10,
  );
  $items['services/design'] = array(
    'title' => 'Design',
    'page callback' => 'design_tab_callback',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'weight' => 0,
  );
  $items['services/seo'] = array(
    'title' => 'SEO',
    'page callback' => 'seo_tab_callback',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'weight' => 10,  
  );
  $items['services/hosting'] = array(
    'title' => 'Hosting',
    'page callback' => 'hosting_tab_callback',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'weight' => 30,
  );
  $items['services/support'] = array(
    'title' => 'Support',
    'page callback' => 'support_tab_callback',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'weight' => 40,
  );

  return $items;
}
```

for more info see the documentation for [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_menu/6).

Comment: @starsinmypockets Thank you! i have know idea about PHP. and studying drupal API? I think  it takes long time. I'm not lazy :) but don't want to wast much time time  :) could you tell me what to do.  where should i put that code? or some easy clue for beginner.   Thanks