# How to create tabbed menu consisting of views and a contact form while having unique paths for each tab?

Tags: 7, routes

I'd like to create a tabbed menu of my support page like this:

```
           | FAQ | Contact us |
```

I'm using views accordion to create a view for my FAQ, but I'm using the contact form for my Contact form.

How can I combine them in a same menu tab while having each tab have its own path so that I can theme the current tab using a:active and for seo purposes?

I've tried quicktabs and block tabs, which work but doesn't give me separate paths. The node tabs module comes close but it doesn't seem to be able to work with a form.

I'm thinking I might need to build it programmatically using a custom module and hook_menu: [How can I create a simple tab?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-can-i-create-a-simple-tab) but I'd prefer not going into that if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your "Contact us" page is not the default Drupal contact page, but a [webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform) (i.e. a node), you could use views to create tabs (see [this tutorial](http://www.wdtutorials.com/2013/07/24/drupal-7-tutorial-how-create-tabs-views), for example). In that case you would create a view that shows just the one webform node and configure it the way that it is displayed as a tab - and the FAQ view as default tab.

I suppose that there is also a workaround [embedding the contact form](https://drupal.org/node/335020) instead of using a webform node.

Comment: Webform would work but since I couldn't get the code to work (might be for d6, I don't know) I tried the module http://drupal.org/project/contact_form_on_node in the comments of the page you links  and it worked! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using [Quick Tabs](https://drupal.org/project/quicktabs).

> The Quick Tabs module allows you to create blocks of tabbed content, specifically views, blocks, nodes* and other quicktabs*. You can create a block on your site containing multiple tabs with corresponding content.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply :) I've tried it and it doesn't give me separate parts. My |FAQ|Contact us| tab on my support page returns something like /support#arg=0, which doesn't work well for theming a:visited and seo